# Error Uncaught Whoops\Exception\ErrorException: Declaration of Concrete\Core\Workflow\Progress\PageProgress

Tags: concrete5

I created a new sub-page and I had noticed the urls on the home page carousel were not working, so I updated them and changed the text in the carousel.Then I getting below error

```
Uncaught Whoops\Exception\ErrorException: Declaration of Concrete\Core\Workflow\Progress\PageProgress::add(Concrete\Core\Workflow\Workflow $wf, Concrete\Core\Workflow\Request\PageRequest $wr) should be compatible with Concrete\Core\Workflow\Progress\Progress::add($wpCategoryHandle, Concrete\Core\Workflow\Workflow $wf, Concrete\Core\Workflow\Request\Request $wr) in /homepages/32/d600934559/htdocs/knowanddo/concrete/src/Workflow/Progress/PageProgress.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/32/d600934559/htdocs/knowanddo/concrete/src/Workflow/Progress/PageProgress.php(8): Whoops\Run->handleError(2, 'Declaration of ...', '/homepages/32/d...', 8, Array) #1 /homepages/32/d600934559/htdocs/knowanddo/concrete/vendor/symfony/class-loader/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/Psr4ClassLoader.php(69): require('/homepages/32/d...') #2 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\Psr4ClassLoader->loadClass('Concrete\\Core\\W...') #3 /homepages/32/d600934559/htdocs/knowanddo/concrete/elements/page_controls_footer.php(12): spl_autol
```